# Batch insert MongoDB and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on MongoDB 2.6.9 and NodeJs 0.10.37 and according to my previous question [MongoDB calculating score from an existing fields and put it in a new field in the same collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926618/mongodb-calculating-score-from-an-existing-fields-and-put-it-in-a-new-field-in-t/36932947#36932947) and I have got a structured answer for doing that from [chridam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam) just like this :

```
var bulkUpdateOps = db.collection1.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    cursor = db.collection1.find(), // cursor 
    counter = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    // computations
    var c1, c2, c3, c4, Field8;
    c1 = 10 + (0.03*doc.Field3);
    c2 = (doc.Field2 == 1) ? 1: 0.03;
    c3 = 7 - (doc.Field5.match(new RegExp(".", "g")) || []).length;
    c4 = (doc.Field2 == 1) ? Math.pow(doc.Field, -0.6) : 1;
    Field8 = c1*c2*c3*c4;

    bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "Field8": Field8 }
    });

    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulkUpdateOps.execute();
        bulkUpdateOps = db.collection1.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if (counter % 500 != 0) { bulkUpdateOps.execute(); }
```

But I still don't know from where start to achieve the above, I should create a js file which will do this Batch insert for me. From mongoose connection to this Batch insert.

Comment: I tried to create a js file batch.js which contains this code :

//connect to DB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb');

and the code given in the solution above;

But when I try to compile it I get these errors please help !


SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the underlying bulk operations API in Mongoose, you should be able to access it via the `.collection` property from the mongoose model. Before using the API, wait for mongoose to successfully connect to the db since Mongoose doesn't really support the "initializeOrderedBulkOp()" currently as it doesn't work with its internal buffering system. So something like the following implementation (not tested) should give you an idea:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
var collection1Schema = new Schema({},{ strict: false, collection: 'Collection1' }),    
    MyModel = mongoose.model("MyModel", collection1Schema );

mongoose.set('debug', true);

mongoose.connection.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;  
    var bulkUpdateOps = MyModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(), 
        counter = 0;

    MyModel.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err; 

        docs.forEach(function (doc){
            // computations
            var c1, c2, c3, c4, Field8;
            c1 = 10 + (0.03*doc.Field3);
            c2 = (doc.Field2 == 1) ? 1: 0.03;
            c3 = 7 - (doc.Field5.match(new RegExp(".", "g")) || []).length;
            c4 = (doc.Field2 == 1) ? Math.pow(doc.Field, -0.6) : 1;
            Field8 = c1*c2*c3*c4;

            counter++;

            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
                "$set": { "Field8": Field8 }
            });

            if (counter % 500 == 0 ) {
                bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;  
                    bulkUpdateOps = MyModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                    console.log(result);
                });
            } 

        });     

        if (counter % 500 != 0 ) {            
            bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;  
                console.log(result);
            });         
        }       
    });

    var app = express();
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('now listening on http://localhost:3000');
    });
});
```