# How to Insert/Save Array of JSON Objects to MongoDB from API?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From Facebook's API I get an Array of 25 JSON objects back that I want to save to my Mongo database, how do I accomplish that using NodeJS, MongoDB/mongoose, superagent/request?

Do I iterate over the array of objects or how would I do it?

This is how each Object looks like:

```
{
"message": "I phone 5s 16 gb\nkr.1,000 - Vejen, Ribe, Denmark\n\n16 gb space grey .Ingenfejl i skærmen og original.\nCa.2,5 gammel .Telefonen virker perfekt.\nUbetydelig lille bule i bagside.\n\nBYD BYD BYD",
"from": {
"name": "Yalnız Kurt",
"id": "10212529378940059"
},
"name": "Photos from Yalnız Kurt's post",
"permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/306677009409252/permalink/1332619516814991/?sale_post_id=1332619516814991",
"type": "photo",
"created_time": "2017-04-24T14:29:15+0000",
"picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/18118670_10212529315698478_3112710548797328966_n.jpg?oh=b730b6621f2b50e43d3a646ce79b98ff&oe=5974B1DE",
"id": "306677009409252_1332619516814991"
}
```

Comment: If you are interested as saving the array as a whole, then write an api to update a mongoose document. If you are looking to `push` each object in the array into a database array that keeps collecting more data, you will need to iterate through the objects.

Comment: Yea, I want to push each object in the array into the database, but I will be hitting the endpoint quite alot, and there could be returned 100 objects each time, but the best way is just to iterate over the array and save each object? :)

Comment: Check this out, might help you: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pushAll/, note the deprecation and the use of $push and $each

Comment: You are after bulk inserts. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983963/batch-insert-mongodb-and-nodejs for examples.